# set value in session using if condition it true 2 condition any time

Tags: php

i have send one value from jQuery to php and in check condition if session value is no set it set value in first condtion is true after it check second condition in if elseif  elseif  else statesment

**Here Is my Code**

```
if(isset($_GET['id1'])) {
    $id1=$_GET['id1']; 
    if(!isset($_SESSION["cmp1"])) { 
        $_SESSION["cmp1"]=$id1; } 
    elseif(!isset($_SESSION["cmp2"])) {
        $_SESSION["cmp2"]=$id1; 
    } elseif(!isset($_SESSION["cmp3"])) {
        $_SESSION["cmp3"]=$id1; 
    } 
    else {  
        echo" <script language='javascript'> alert('you have allready add 3 item to compair'); </script>";  
    } 
}
```

Comment: if(isset($_GET['id1']))
 {
 $id1=$_GET['id1'];
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION["cmp1"]))
 {
 $_SESSION["cmp1"]=$id1;
 }
 elseif(!isset($_SESSION["cmp2"]))
 {
 $_SESSION["cmp2"]=$id1;
 }
 elseif(!isset($_SESSION["cmp3"]))
 {
 $_SESSION["cmp3"]=$id1;
 }
 else
 { 
 echo"
 <script language='javascript'>
 alert('you have allready add 3 item to compair');
 </script>"; 
 
 }
 }

Comment: Hi. You may need to rephrase what you are asking. What you have currently wrote does not appear to be a question. Let us know what your problem is. Thanks.

Comment: what i can do in this condition if elseif elseif else are check condition after first condition is true

Comment: Edit your question to include the code from your comment into a properly formatted `code-block` and you may get a better response.  Also see [mcve].